# How much were telegraphists in the 1950s paid?

Tags: united-states, technology, money

I'm doing some research for a small project, and am having some difficulty finding information on telegraphists as a whole.

The information I'm trying to find is rather specific, and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

In the 1950s, how much would a telegraphist have been paid? I realize that at the time, telegraphy unions were forming, so if some specificity is needed, I'd like to know:

- What a railroad telegrapher's average pay was before railroad telegraphers' unions, and
- what it was *after* unions began fighting for higher pay,
- what it was in the U.S. military (specifically, in the Navy, if it matters).

I realize these are somewhat specific questions - however, I have no clue where to look to find this information. If anyone could help, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

An enlisted Naval serviceman was paid [anything from $80 to $213/month](https://www.navycs.com/charts/1949-military-pay-chart.html), depending on rank and service. I can't find a clear US record, but [the Canadians](http://jproc.ca/rrp/opin5060.html) had the lowest (non-training) telegraphist grade as an Able Seaman, and this seems to be at the E-3 level; so by analogy say $100/month. To make it directly comparable to civilian pay we need to account for board and lodging; where the Navy didn't provide these our E-3 would [get an allowance](https://www.navycs.com/charts/1949-basic-allowance.html) of $45 (lodging) and $2.25/day (food) - so say $112.50 allowance, for a total of $212.50.

[This report](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OYlgBXCrGVcC) will contain more information than you could possibly want on wages by grade & year for Western Union employees, including discussion of the major pay discussions. Based on Table 2a, a mid-range morse telegraphist could expect $1.24/hour in 1948, $1.41 in 1951, and $1.54-1.69 by 1953.

As an aside, it's worth bearing in mind that unionisation in the industry seems to have begun well before the 1950s (there's some fairly extensive discussion [here](http://monoskop.org/images/f/f3/Jepsen_Thomas_My_Sisters_Telegraphic_Women_in_the_Telegraph_Office_1846-1950.pdf)), so the postwar activity won't reflect the improvement over an *entirely* non-unionised starting point.

So, how do they compare? In the Navy, assuming he had to find his own bed and board, he'd get $212.50, plus $9 sea pay if applicable, and a further $45 hazardous-duty pay if he did submarine or aviation duty. Or, he could go into civilian work and get about $230/month (five days a week for eight hours at a time), more with overtime or longer hours (not sure if a five, six, or five-and-a-half-day week was standard then). Civilian pay looks a bit better, but not overwhelmingly so.

Comment: I am... actually flat-out dumbstruck that you managed to find this information so quickly. Thank you _so much_.

Comment: @Emrakul no problem, I like a challenge :-)

Comment: $212.50 a month would be equivalent to $2,089.88 a month today, according to http://data.bls.gov/cgi-bin/cpicalc.pl?cost1=212.50&year1=1950&year2=2015

Comment: Hmm, sea pay and submarine pay while not having a navy provided room and board, that would suck. "Hey buddy, shift's over, go outside"